Implementing the Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm for Sampling from the Conway-Maxwell-Poisson (CMP) Distribution
I'm working with the Conway-Maxwell-Poisson (CMP) distribution, which has the probability mass function:
$$
P(X = x) = f(x;  \lambda, \nu) = \frac{\lambda^x}{(x!)^\nu Z(\lambda, \nu)}
$$
where $ Z(\lambda, \nu) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^x}{(x!)^\nu} $ is the normalization constant.
I would like to use the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to sample from this distribution. I understand that the kernel of the CMP distribution, $ \lambda^x / (x!)^\nu $, is similar to that of a Poisson distribution, and I was planning to use a Poisson distribution as my proposal. However, I'm struggling to proceed with the next steps of the algorithm.
Additionally, I initially tried using the discrete inversion method to sample from the CMP, but since the cumulative distribution function (CDF) does not have a closed form, this approach did not work for me.
Could you provide guidance on how to implement Metropolis-Hastings for the CMP distribution, or suggest an alternative sampling method (e.g., rejection sampling)?

You could try this rejection sampler, which adapts the choice of envelope to the parameters: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/volume-16/issue-3/Bayesian-Inference-Model-Selection-and-Likelihood-Estimation-using-Fast-Rejection/10.1214/20-BA1230.full?tab=ArticleLink. (I'm not writing this as an answer, because the method is a bit too involved for me to accurately summarize.)

Thank you so much for your help. I will take a look at the article you mentioned.
